# can wkhtmltopdf use GPU on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, gpu, odoo, wkhtmltopdf

Cant seem to find a clear answer for this. Can wkhtmltopdf use the gpu at all?

Context: Generating reports on my Ubuntu 14.04 Odoo server is extremely slow. On my windows test machine, its nearly instant.